# Why is it recommended for Meta Packages to rely on the implicit version specified by the SDK?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to understand why Microsoft recommends not to specify an explicit version for Meta Package.

I am new to dot net core and I am trying to understand the importance of implicit versioning with respect to Meta Packages in web.config file.
I also went through [github discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6430) about the implicit version. But I didn't understand much.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I wanted to know what are the disadvantages of mentioning version explicitly in the above code?

Comment: Let's say MS fix a security issue, they want you to get it along with the new version of the package automatically. If you check for example https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1 you'll see that numerous version of tagged as 'security patch'

Comment: Specifying a version number on the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App reference does not guarantee that version of the shared framework will be chosen. Refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.2)